# How to block both IPv4 and IPv6 with ipset on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ipset

So I have the following script that blocks IPs:

```
#!/bin/bash
# here's your list of IPS
CURRENT_BL=/path/to/my/ip_black_list.txt
# create/flush recreate the tables
iptables -F BLACKHOLE
iptables -N BLACKHOLE 
for BAD_IP in $(cat $CURRENT_BL)
do
        ipset add ipset-blacklist $BAD_IP 2>/dev/null || \
                echo "Failed to add ${BAD_IP}"
done
# REJECT the matching target
iptables -A BLACKHOLE -p all -m set --match-set ipset-blacklist src -j REJECT 
iptables -A BLACKHOLE -j RETURN
# assume your nginx is on 80 and 443
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --destination-ports 80,443 -j BLACKHOLE
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --destination-ports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
```

The ipset was created with the following command:

`ipset create ipset-blacklist hash:ip`

It is all working fine with IPv4 now but the problem is wiht IPv6, I am getting the following error - `Syntax error: cannot parse 2003:e6:6f03:7b80:21dc:54c8:ac26:552b: resolving to IPv4 address failed`

How can I make this script to read both types of IPs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create the ipset using the following command:

```
$ sudo ipset create ipset-blacklist hash:ip family inet6
```

The option `family { inet | inet6 }` defines the protocol family of the IP addresses to be stored in the set. By default it is `inet` (IPv4). For more info, you can see `man ipset`.

Also, you need to use `ip6tables` instead of `iptables`. Otherwise, you will get an error similar to this (I created a test6 ipset with family inet6)

> iptables v1.6.0: The protocol family of set test6 is IPv6, which is
>   not applicable.

Comment: Thank you, now I am able to add the IPv6, but the IPv4 is a problem. Is there a way to do this in one signe ipset list, or I should split it in two and do some kind of if statement in the loop?

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab: You need to have two different sets: one for IPv4 and another for IPv6.

Comment: `$ sudo ipset create ipset-blacklist6 hash:ip family inet6` to make it clear you need a 2nd, separate ipv6 set.  As it stands it suggests you can use the same set for both ipv4 and ipv6.