# How to combine ipset IPv4 and IPv6 configurations

Tags: iptables, ipv6, ipset

I'm running Arch Linux and referring to [Simple stateful firewall - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Simple_stateful_firewall#IPv6).

I have two different bash scripts for creating my iptables rules: one for IPv4 and another for IPv6. Each creates one or more `ipset` hash lists (sets) using the appropriate family: inet or inet6.

That approach is supported by [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/955032/68517), "You need to have two different sets: one for IPv4 and another for IPv6."

I use the systemd ipset.service and by default it loads the file `/etc/ipset.conf`. That config file creates my hash lists of banned ip addresses, etc. `ipset` uses only one config file, unlike iptables with /etc/iptables/iptables.rules and /etc/iptables/ip6tables.rules.

Each of my iptables bash scripts has this command near the end:

```
ipset save > /etc/ip6set.conf
```

What is a good way to combine my ipset hash lists into a single config file that will load as expected upon starting the systemd unit? For example, could I run my bash scripts in a specific order and change the second command to `ipset save >> /etc/ip6set.conf` to append instead of replace?

That doesn't seem like a good approach (i.e., it is subject to breakage). How do most people deal with this?

Comment: Use `nftables`?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov: yes, that's the way to go. But for the moment, I have to stay with iptables.